# cytoscape.js angular2 typescript use

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, cytoscape.js

Have an angular4 application packed with Webpack.

want to use cytoscape.js. Need to use npm module for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-cytoscape

I have done changes as in that page , only with a difference

```
import {NgCytoscapeModule} from "ng2-cytoscape";
```

instead of "ng2-cytoscape/dist"; (which was giving compilation errors)

Then added the following lines to app.module.ts

```
import {NgCytoscapeModule}      from 'ng2-cytoscape';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgCytoscapeModule
  ],
```

Also , added the dependency to the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "ng2-cytoscape": "^0.2.0",
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
compiler.es5.js:1540 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'NgCytoscapeModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1540)
```

What is the reason? Is there another way to use cytoscape.js in Angular 2 - Typescript ?

Comment: probably version issue .. i.e Cytoscape is in angular 2 & Your project is in angular 4.
Can you please post package.json of both

Comment: have added in case it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cytoscape does not have an official support package for Angular.  If you want to use Cytoscape, use the official `cytoscape` package and write your own Angular integration that suits your needs.

Comment: Tried to use version from https://github.com/Fabian-Schmidt/DefinitelyTyped , but seems NOT released in https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped. Hence, can´t import it in package.json. Will need to define an own typing files inside my project;  and import all those definitions into the file that declares the cytoscape methods. Thanks.